# Ember Handlebars Embed ID

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use ember to show a dynamic list of found content.  The problem is that when I try to put handlebars in html attributes, everything breaks.

```
RegApp.PatronsFound = Ember.CollectionView.create
  tagName: 'table'
  content: []
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("<td><button onclick='alert({{content.id}})'>{{content.name}}</button>")
RegApp.PatronsFound.appendTo('body')
```

When it is fed a piece of content with the ID of 3 and the name FOO, I want this html to be generated:

```
<button onclick="alert(3)">FOO</button>
```

Instead, I get this:

```
<button onclick="alert(&lt;script id=" metamorph-4-start'="" type="text/x-placeholder">3<script id="metamorph-4-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>)'&gt;FOO</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{{unbound content.id}}
```

to arbitrarily insert values into your templates. Normally, such values are wrapped in metamorph tags which allow the displayed value to be bound to the backing value, and updated whenever the backing value changes. This only works if the output is regular HTML, not, in this case, spanning event handlers and embedded JS. {{unbound}} inserts the value at that property path once, without metamorph tags, and without being updated if that value changes in the future.